# Logistic Curve Problems

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to plot a logistic curve using ggplot but I keep getting a straight line on my graph (as opposed to a curved line). My dependent variable (Y) is binary and my independent variable (X) is continuous. This is the script I am using:

```
 ggplot(data=ice, aes(X,Y)) + 
 geom_point(position=position_jitter(h=.01, w=.1)) + 
 geom_smooth(method='glm', method.args = 
 list(start=c(tau=0.2,Vmax=2)), 
 se=TRUE) + 
 labs(title='Title') + 
 xlab('X') + 
 ylab('Y')
```

What is strange is that the following code used to work:

```
 ggplot(data=ice, aes(X,Y)) + 
 geom_point(position=position_jitter(h=.01, w=.1)) + 
 stat_smooth(method='glm', family="binomial") + 
 labs(title='Title') + 
 xlab('X') + 
 ylab('Y')
```

but I now get the error:

```
Error: Unknown parameters: family
```

What is missing from my new code?

Comment: You must have updated your version of ggplot2. Like you said, the code *used* to work. But the new version changed the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
ggplot(data=ice, aes(X,Y)) + 
 geom_point(position=position_jitter(h=.01, w=.1)) + 
 stat_smooth(method='glm', method.args=list(family="binomial")) + 
 labs(title='Title') + 
 xlab('X') + 
 ylab('Y')
```